# req.body returns undefined even though it worked before

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, undefined, body-parser

req.body is undefined even though it worked a couple of days ago, i even tried using the now depreciated body-parser and nothing, this is my code:

**JS:**

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express();
require("dotenv").config();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

router.use(express.json());
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.get("/upload-new", function (req, res) {
  res.render("forum2");
});

router.post("/upload-new", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.name);
});
```

**EJS:**

```
  <body>
    <form action="/upload-new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0-beta1",
    "connect": "^3.7.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.6.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "mongodb": "^4.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.18",
    "package-json": "^8.1.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  }
}
```

I've been really struggling with this issue for the past few days, any help would be *appreciated*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML form is configured for `"multipart/form-data"`, but you have no middleware on your server to read and parse that content type so therefore `req.body` remains `undefined` since no middleware matched the content-type.

For such a simple form, you can just use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content-type (which is the default content-type when none is specified) and your `app.use(express.urlencoded())` will read and parse that content-type and will fill `req.body` for you.

Just remove the enctype in your form and it will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
  <body>
    <form action="/upload-new" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
```